# Javascript Arbitrary sort array based on values of a field

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

So I have an array of object which looks like this:

```
var myArray = [{priority : "low"}, {priority: "critical"}, {priority: "high"}]
```

I need to sort in this way: 1)Critical, 2) High and 3) Low.

how can this be done?

Comment: At starters, read [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) at MDN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest to use an object for the storing of the sort order.

If you need a default value for sorting, you could use a value for sorting unknown priority to start or to the end.

```js
var sort = ['critical', 'high', 'low'],
    defaultValue = Infinity,
    sortObj = {},
    myArray = [{ priority: "unknown" }, { priority: "low" }, { priority: "critical" }, { priority: "high" }];

sort.forEach(function (a, i) { sortObj[a] = i + 1; });

myArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (sortObj[a.priority] || defaultValue) - (sortObj[b.priority] || defaultValue);
});
 
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: this should have been accepted answer from beginning thanks

Comment: Premature optimizations.... `(a, b) => sort.indexOf(a.priority) - sort.indexOf(b.priority)` would be much simpler.

Comment: @georg, i am not a fan of `indexOf`.

Answer (score 5):

Use an object that maps priority names to numbers, then sort based on that.

```js
var priorities = {
  low: 0,
  high: 1,
  critical: 2
};

var myArray = [{
  priority: "low"
}, {
  priority: "critical"
}, {
  priority: "high"
}]

myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return priorities[b.priority] - priorities[a.priority];
});

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Not an arbitrary sort, though.

Comment: The associations between priority names and values in the object are arbitrary.